# Check VRP instance is feasibility

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, vehicle-routing, knapsack, feasible-points

Beforehand, this is a very long thread, in case you want to know in advance, to see if this thread's interests match with yours, this thread concerns fast ways of determining whether a VRP instance is feasible.

Now that you are aware of the risks. Let's go!

Before I describe my current problem, I will first detail in what context it will be applied.
I am proposing a solution methodology for *Team Orienteering Problems* (**TOPs**).
In this methodology, I am considering the problem as a *knapsack* problem variant.
Let's define the notations of the **TOP** to substantiate the next results.

**Problem definition:**

Let:

- $D(V, A)$ be a digraph;
- $0 \in V$ be the depot node;
- $t_a \in \mathbb{R}$ be the arc $a \in A$ traversing time;
- $p_i \in \mathbb{R}$ be the node $i \in V$ profit, where $p_0 = 0$;
- $M$ be the available vehicles set;
- $T$ be each vehicle's time limit.

A feasible solution $S = \{R: R \text{ is a sequence of nodes in $V$ beginning and ending at the node $0$}\}$ for the **TOP** is a set of at most $|M|$ routes, such that every route respects the vehicle time limit $T$.
An optimal solution $S^{*}$ for the **TOP** is a set of routes that maximizes the function $\sum_{i \in \bigcup_{R \in S} R} p_i$, i.e., the sum of the profits of all visited nodes where a profit is not counted more than once even if the solution visits a node twice or more. Note that, the routes, not necessarily, will have minimum time consumption, since it is not a problem's requirement.

***Knapsack* solution methodology:**

Knowing that a route, not necessarily, will have minimum time consumption.
I was thinking of solving this problem in two steps.
First, finding the set of nodes that composes an optimal solution, using the constrained *knapsack*  problem.
And second, finding a *Distance Constrained Capacitated **VRP*** (**DCVRP**), a **VRP** variant where the only capacity is on the vehicle's time limit, feasible solution for the instance composed by the vehicle time limit $T$ and the digraph $D$ induced by the nodes found by the constrained *knapsack* problem.
Specifically, I execute an unconstrained *knapsack* formulation,

$$K(V) = \text{max}_{y \in \mathbb{B}^{|V|}} \sum_{i \in V} y_i p_i$$

, and then I check whether there is a **DCVRP** feasible solution for the instance composed by the vehicle time limit $T$, and the digraph $D$ induced by the nodes used in $y^{*}$, where $y^{*}$ is the $K(V)$ optimal solution. Formally, the induced digraph can be defined as:

$$D^{'}(V^{'} = (\{i \in V : y^{*}_i = 1\} \cup \{0\}), \quad A^{'} = \{(i, j) \in A : i \in V^{'} \wedge j \in V^{'}\})$$

If the digraph $D^{'}$ along with $T$ results in a **DCVRP** feasible instance, then we have found the set of nodes that composes an optimal **TOP** solution for the **TOP** instance digraph $D$, otherwise, we add the following constraint to $K(V)$:

$$
\sum_{i \in V^{'}} y_i \leqslant |V^{'}| - 1
$$

And we execute $K(V)$ again, till we get a set of nodes $V^{'}$ that leads to a feasible **DCVRP** instance. Formally, consider the algorithm ***KnapDCVRP*** below:

1. Let $y^{*}$ be a $K(V)$ optimal solution;
2. Let $D^{'}(V^{'}, A^{'})$ be the induced digraph, built over $y^{*}$;
3. If $(T, D^{'})$ is a **DCVRP** feasible instance, then return $V^{'}$, and exit program;
4. Add to $K(V)$ the constraint $\sum_{i \in V^{'}} y_i \leqslant |V^{'}| - 1$;
5. Go to **1**.

**DCVRP feasibility checking:**

In this methodology, the major problem I am facing concerns the algorithm ***KnapDCVRP***'s step 3, i.e. how to determine whether a **DCVRP** instance is feasible.
To do this, I convert the $D^{'}$ digraph into a complete digraph $D^{''}(V^{'}, A^{''} = A^{'} \cup \{(i, j) \in V^{'2}: (i, j) \notin A^{'} \wedge i \neq j\})$, and I consider the time weights as

$$
t^{''}_{(i, j)} = 
\begin{cases}
t_{(i, j)}, \quad \text{if } (i, j) \in A^{'}\\
\text{the shortest path time between nodes $i$ and $j$ in $D^{'}$}, \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

for all $(i, j) \in A^{''}$.
And then I execute the following MILP program:

$$
\sum_{a \in \delta^{+}(i)} x_a = \sum_{a \in \delta^{-}(i)} x_a = 1 \quad \forall i \in V^{'} \backslash \{0\} \quad (1)
\\
\sum_{a \in \delta^{+}(0)} x_a = \sum_{a \in \delta^{-}(0)} x_a = |M|  \quad (2)
\\
\sum_{i \in V^{'} : i\neq j} u_{(j, i)} - u_{(i, j)} + x_{(i, j)} t^{''}_{(i, j)} = 0 \quad \forall j \in V^{'} \backslash \{0\} \quad (3)
\\
u_{(0, i)} = 0 \quad \forall i \in V^{'} \backslash\{0\} \quad (4)
\\
u_{(j, 0)} \geqslant x_{(j, 0)} t^{''}_{(0, j)} \quad \forall j \in V^{'} \backslash \{0\} \quad (5)
\\
u_{(j, 0)} \leqslant x_{(j, 0)} (T - t^{''}_{(j, 0)}) \quad \forall j \in V^{'} \backslash \{0\} \quad (6)
\\
u_{(i, j)} \geqslant x_{(i, j)} max\{t^{''}_{(depot, j)} - t^{''}_{(i, j)}, t^{''}_{(0, i)}\} \quad \forall (i, j) \in A^{''} : i, j \neq 0 \quad (7)
\\
u_{(i, j)} \leqslant x_{(i, j)} min\{T - t^{''}_{(j, 0)} - t^{''}_{(i, j)}, T - t^{''}_{(i, depot)}\} \quad \forall (i, j) \in A^{''} : i, j \neq 0  \quad (8)
\\
x \in \mathbb{B}^{|V^{'}|} \quad (9)
\\
u \in \mathbb{R}^{A^{''}}_{+} \quad (10)
$$

The constraints (1) and (2) are **VRP**'s well known.
Regarding the remaining ones, (3-10), are arc flow constraints to avoid subcycles disconnected from the depot, even in fractional solutions, and, at the same time, impose the vehicle's time limit constraint.
I know they seem to be a little bit unusual since there's no big $M$ on it, but they were already used in another routing problem and had proven to be very efficient (look [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tre.2017.06.003) at subsection 3.4 on page 10, and [here](http://repositorio.unicamp.br/jspui/handle/REPOSIP/357117) at subsection 6.3 on page 50).

I have executed the MILP formulation (1-10) in the CPLEX solver using the following parameters configuration:

- CPX_PARAM_INTSOLLIM = 1 (Just find a feasible solution, if it exists);
- CPX_PARAM_MIPEMPHASIS = 1 (Emphasize feasibility over optimality);
- CPX_PARAM_VARSEL = -1 (Branch on variable with minimum infeasibility)

Note that the formulation (1-10) has no objective function and that the CPLEX chosen parameters are tuned to find integer feasible solutions, rather than optimizing.
These choices were made since I just want to determine whether the **DCVRP** instance is feasible.

The problem regarding this procedure is that it is taking, relatively speaking, too long, about ~1 minute for 100 nodes, to check whether an instance is feasible.
In this solution methodology, the algorithm **KnapDCVRP**'s step **3** may be executed many times, even hundreds, thus, having a fast procedure to check the feasibility of a **DCVRP** instance can make a huge difference, depending on the instance size.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way of determining whether a **DCVRP** instance is feasible in a very fast time.
I already tried to use the Google OR-Tools and Dynamic Programming approaches, but they are taking too much time, indeed they are slower than the (1-10) MILP formulation.

I know this is a very long thread, and the reader now may be thinking "well he could just have stated he needed some fast procedure to check a VRP instance feasibility", but I think it is important to make the context clear.
If anyone has any questions or found any errors, please let me know.

Comment: You are essentially doing combinatorial Benders decomposition with "no-good" feasibility cuts, and the resulting DCVRP subproblem is difficult.  You might be better off changing the master problem to determine not just which nodes are visited but which nodes are visited by which vehicles.  The subproblem then decomposes into identical subproblems (one per vehicle), each of which is easier and yields stronger feasibility cuts (that can also be shared by all vehicles in the master problem).

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for the answer. Yes, you are right. I was thinking of considering a variable w_{ij}, to express whether the node i is placed in the route j, in the K(V) program, like a bin packing fashion. Thence, the subproblem now becomes to determine whether there exist a tour of length at most T that visits all the nodes allocated to the route (bin) j, that is, find a tour that services all the nodes in {i \in V: w_{ij} = 1} and has time consumption at most T. Is that what do you mean? Thank you and regards.

Comment: Yes, and for that one-vehicle subproblem, you need "only" solve a TSP.  I did something similar in [this paper](https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2018/1758-2018.pdf).

Comment: Very thank you @RobPratt, I definitively will check it out.

Comment: Two implementation details that should reduce the run time: 1. If a TSP subproblem yields an optimal value $>T$, that yields a feasibility cut, but you can look for a minimal such cut by removing one node at a time until the TSP value is $\le T$.  This idea often appears in "no-good" feasibility cuts.  You want to identify a source of infeasibility that cuts off a set of solutions rather than just one solution.  2. The second idea is to apply any feasibility cuts to all bins in the master.  Without doing this, the master is likely to return essentially the same solution many times.

Comment: @RobPratt, yes. You are right. And we could improve this procedure even more, by calculating LBs for the TSP and checking whether any of the LBs leads to a time consumption greater than T. By doing this, we would be able to, in some cases, cut off a set of nodes from the solution without, even, running a TSP algorithm.

Comment: @RobPratt thank you for all the support. I do not want to be rude, but I am developing another approach for this problem, and I would like to know if you can give feedback.

Comment: @RobPratt At this very moment, I am working with a Genetic Algorithm (GA) for this problem. And in this algorithm, I am considering as chromosome's alleles the nodes (and not the arcs, as generally is done when solving routing problems through GAs), like a knapsack GA fashion, selecting the alleles (nodes) with weight > 0.5, and executing the MILP model (1-9) described above. It is like in the KnapDCVRP, I am considering the y* = {1, if allele[i] > 0.5, and 0 otherwise for all i in V}.

Comment: @RobPratt However, I fall into the same problem of this thread, "How can I determine whether the set y* leads to a DCVRP feasible solution?". Do you see any way of using a GA, that considers the alleles as nodes rather than arcs, for this case? More specifically, I want to take out, from the master problem, the responsibility of determining the sequence of the nodes.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions for GA, but neither master problem discussed so far (with $y_i$ or $w_{ij}$) determines the sequence of nodes.